Adjust vertical scrollbar range in Excel userform listbox
I have a dynamic multicolumn listbox which can range from 1 to 100 rows. The userform has a fixed height, therefore a vertical scrollbar shows when required.
When 100 rows are listed, the scrollbar understands there are 500-600 of them, leading to an empty area at the bottom.
How do I set the scrollbar to automatically fit to the number of listed rows?
Code that fills the listbox:
Sub RefreshLBIndoor()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Byte
    With ListBoxIndoor ' This is the listbox name
        .ColumnCount = 6
        j = 1
        For i = 3 To SupportList.ListObjects("ProductList_table").DataBodyRange.Rows.Count + 2 ' Data begins from row 3
            ' Column F (number 6) contains the filter for which rows to populate the listbox
            If InStr(1, SupportList.Cells(i, 6), "Example", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then 
                For k = 3 To 8
                    .AddItem
                    .Column(k - 3, j - 1) = SupportList.Cells(i, k).Value
                Next k
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next i
        On Error Resume Next
        .ListIndex = 0
    End With
End Sub


Excel does not expose the ScrollHeight properly a ListBox'  It sounds like you are using a range for the rowsource.  If so include the rowsource range in your post and I'll show you how to make the range dynamic.

Hi TinMan, my RowSource definition is empty. Instead, in the code I use .AddItem that goes through a range, checks for some conditions and then populates the listbox

Why are you adding empty rows?

The listbox is empty. Code fills it based on conditions applied on the range, there is no empty row as result

Could you please add your code that fills the listbox to the post.  If there are no empty rows, then the listbox should be sized correctly.

Sub RefreshLBIndoor()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Byte
With ListBoxIndoor 'This is listbox name
.ColumnCount = 6
j = 1
For i = 3 To SupportList.ListObjects("ProductList_table").DataBodyRange.Rows.Count + 2 'Data begins from row 3
If InStr(1, SupportList.Cells(i, 6), "Example", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then 'Column F (number 6) contains filter for which rows to populate the listbox
For k = 3 To 8
.AddItem
.Column(k - 3, j - 1) = SupportList.Cells(i, k).Value
Next k
j = j + 1
End If
Next i
On Error Resume Next
.ListIndex = 0
End With
End Sub

Variable k is used because data is at columns 3 to 8

I improved my answer showing how to better utilize the ListObject.

The issue is that an item was being added for each column in each row.  Moving .AddItem outside of the column loop fixed the problem.  I also added .Clear to clear the listbox on refresh.
Sub RefreshLBIndoor()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Byte
    With ListBoxIndoor ' This is the listbox name
        Rem Clear the listbox when you refresh it
        .Clear
        .ColumnCount = 6
        j = 1
        For i = 3 To SupportList.ListObjects("ProductList_table").DataBodyRange.Rows.Count + 2 ' Data begins from row 3
            ' Column F (number 6) contains the filter for which rows to populate the listbox
            If InStr(1, SupportList.Cells(i, 6), "Example", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                Rem AddItem once per row
                .AddItem
                For k = 3 To 8
                    .Column(k - 3, j - 1) = SupportList.Cells(i, k).Value
                Next k
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next i
        On Error Resume Next
        .ListIndex = 0
    End With
End Sub

Here is an improved version of my answer that takes advantage of the data being stored in a ListObject:
Sub RefreshLBIndoor()
    Rem use Long for your counters
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    
    Dim Values As Variant
    With ListBoxIndoor ' This is the listbox name
        Rem Clear the listbox when you refresh it
        .Clear
        .ColumnCount = 6
        Rem Load the Values into an array to improve efficiency
        Values = SupportList.ListObjects("ProductList_table").DataBodyRange.Value
        For r = 1 To SupportList.ListObjects("ProductList_table").ListRows.Count
            If InStr(1, SupportList.Cells(r, 6), "Example", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                Rem AddItem once per row
                .AddItem
                For c = 3 To 8
                    .Column(c - 3, .ListCount - 1) = Values(r, c)
                Next
            End If
        Next
        On Error Resume Next
        .ListIndex = 0
    End With
End Sub

